# how can i check if a string contains another string throughout it

Tags: python, string

I have two lists of strings and i want to check if the words within one list contain the strings within the other list throughout

Here is an example of what i mean:

```
l1 = ["heollo", "leetcode"], l2 = ["e", "oo"]
```

the return value should be

> "heollo"

from this as it contains `"oo"` throughout and `"e"` too

I understand that regex and wildcards can be used but i tried something like this:

```
string = "heollo"
pattern = "*o*o*"
match = fnmatch.fnmatch(string, pattern)
print(match)
```

Now this does what i want but how am i able to take the values from my list like `"oo"` and amend them to allow anything before, between, or after like if i had `"jjj"` how can i make it become `"*j*j*j*"` or is there a better way of going about this problem thanks

Comment: So you are asking how to add asterisks throughout a string?

Comment: yes basically i want to check if "oo" so bascially if two o's are throughout a string they don't need to be like "book" i just want to check if the string i have has two o's throughout it

Comment: now i want to be able to check but if any string is contained within another string so basically check again say if "ceo" is contained within "facebook" which it is as there is a "c" an "o" and an "e" all present in the string facebook

Comment: So you are asking how to add asterisks throughout a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work:

```
import re
l1 = ["heollo", "leetcode"]
l2 = ["e", "oo"]
patterns = ['.*'.join(list(item)) for item in l2]
# patterns is ['e', 'o.*o']
result = [item for item in l1 if all(
    [re.search(pattern, item) is not None for pattern in patterns]
)]
# ['heollo']
```

I've corrected your regex here: you want `.*` - the `*` means match 0 or more, the `.` means match any character. Together, it means match 0 or more occurrences of any character. If `pattern` is not in `item`, then `re.search(pattern, item)` returns `None`, hence we only keep items that do not return `None` for any of the searches.

Comment: thank you my friend i have a good bit of programming knowledge but only a little with python so i was unsure how to actually implement it but i knew the methodology and logic needed thank you bro